# How can I remove a project from the project list on XCode Welcome screen?

Tags: xcode

I have an XCode project that I tried to delete manually, and I did delete it, but some reference is left - apparently. This reference is making this project still display on the Welcome screen of XCode (XCode version 7.3) on El Capitan. If I try to double click on this non-existing project I get message in a popup "The file 'project.xcworkspace' doesn’t exist." and after that, when I click OK in that popup, I get another popup with message "The file 'Skocko.xcodeproj' doesn’t exist."
How can I completely remove this project and not have it on Welcome page, since it is very confusing issue?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Open Xcode and go to `File --> Open Recent`.  From there select `Clear Menu`.  This will remove the shortcut to your most recent projects.  Close Xcode and reopen it.  Skocko project should be gone from the Welcome screen.

Comment: Great, all the other projects recently opened are gone too, but this is not an issue, I can reopen them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option that works is to delete the project folder. Obviously you might not want to do this, but a valid reason for not wanting the project listed on startup is that you do not want the project anymore.

Comment: this does not work. I deleted my project folder and the reference still appears in the welcome screen. Only the other answer (Clear menu) works.